# Hive shell not opening when I have hive-site.xml and other errors

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm relatively new to Hive. I installed Hive 2.3.2 on a Vagrant VM but I have been having issues when running Hive.

I installed it as follows:

```
wget http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/www.apache.org/dist/hive/hive-2.3.2/apache-hive-2.3.2-bin.tar.gz
tar -xzf apache-hive-2.3.2-bin.tar.gz
sudo mv apache-hive-2.3.2-bin /usr/local/hive
```

I then added the following to my bashrc:

```
export HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/hive
export HIVE_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hive/conf
export PATH=$HIVE_HOME/bin:$PATH
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/*:.
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/hive/lib/*:.
```

I then added the following to my hive-config.sh

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
```

And ran the followings commands:

```
sudo $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -mkdir -p     /tmp
sudo $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -mkdir -p    /user/hive/warehouse
sudo $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -chmod g+w   /tmp
sudo $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop fs -chmod g+w   /user/hive/warehouse
sudo $HIVE_HOME/bin/schematool -dbType derby -initSchema
```

After this when I run the hive command the hive command line comes up as expected. However when I try any commands show as show tables; I get the following error:

```
FAILED: SemanticException org.apache.hadoop.hive.qlmetadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
```

I was getting this error a few days ago and managed to fix it. However without changing anything yesterday everything stopped working. 
I originally fixed it by doing the following:

First I checked the conf folder and saw that there were only template files in there, so I ran the following commands:

```
sudo cp hive-default.xml.template hive-site.xml
sudo cp hive-env.sh.template hive-env.sh
```

I edited the hive-env.sh file to include the following:

```
export HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=1024
# Set HADOOP_HOME to point to a specific hadoop install directory
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
#hive 
export HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/hive
# Hive Configuration Directory can be controlled by:
export HIVE_CONF_DIR=$HIVE_HOME/conf
```

and then ensured I has access by running:

sudo chmod a+rwx . --recursive

Originally this worked and when I typed in show tables; it ran. However yesterday it stopped working and the HIVE command line will no longer appear. and i get the following error message:

```
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-common-2.3.2.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: ${system:java.io.tmpdir%7D/$%7Bsystem:user.name%7D
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:254)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:212)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:659)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:582)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:549)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java.750)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver:java.686)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoked(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoked(NativeMethodAccessorimpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAcessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorimpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Runjar.run(Runjar.java:239)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Runjar.main(Runjar.java:153)
Caused by: java.netURISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: $(system:java.io.tmpdir%7D/$%7Bsystem:user.name%7D
at java.net.URI.checkPath(URI.java:1823)
at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:745)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:251)
... 12 more
```

I'be been looking online and can;t find anything that fixes the above. The hive command line doesn't even appear anymore with above error.

Any help on this would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

check below configuration ,I hope , it will work.

(1) .bashrc file

```
#HIVE VARIABLE START
export HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/hive
export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin
#HIVE VARIABLE END
```

(2) hive-env.sh

`export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
 export HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=512
 export HIVE_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hive/conf`

(3) hive-site.xml

```
 <property>
    <name>hive.exec.local.scratchdir</name>
    <value>/tmp/${user.name}</value>
    <description></description>
  </property>

<property>
    <name>hive.downloaded.resources.dir</name>
    <value>/tmp/${user.name}_resources</value>
    <description></description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore_db1?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false</value>
    <description></description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
    <value>hiveuser</value>
    <description></description>
</property>
```

(4) copy database connector jar file in

> /usr/local/hive/lib

folder
    i.e if you are using mysql then copy mysql-connector.jar file into lib 
    folder

Comment: most errors that I ran into when running commands in hive were due to not putting the 'sudo' command beforehand. I think this is how I fixed the above issue. Hope this helps